# How to avoid to download the video or image from server once we have seen(Like it should store in cache memory)?

Tags: android

I have problem with my app, it's very slow because of using Video and images. When I play video or show images it takes time to download, the app would close during this time or it will take for ever. 
How can I avoid this problem? 
Once we have seen the image or video it should not download from server again, please give me the solution for this(Like Facebook).

Comment: try androidquery framework to achieve this

Comment: how to use Android query framework, please give me the brief details regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

First you should download the video or image in an asynctask inner class, this is why the app freezes while downloading.
You are downloading on the UI thread and this freezes your app, AsyncTask is the way to go.
Second when download is complete you could save the video, image to sdcard so you won't have to download them again next time. When you want to view the video the second time you will only have to know the file name so you could grab it from sd card. You could make a method that determines if a video on sd card is considered outdated and delete that file if true.

Also as other comments say, AQuery ( Android Query) is a library (facilitates chaining like jQuery does for javascript)  that offers a lot of convenience methods for file downloading and other cool stuff. A short Google query for AQuery term should reveal tutorials and download sources.

Comment: If I save the downloaded video and images in my SD CARD means, my memory also going to low memory, suppose if my video and images exceeds my SD card means what can I do? Another thing, So many user's can upload video and images in my app, so the memory size also going to large, in that occasion what we will do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AndroidVideoCache](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache) for caching video while streaming. It allow to use cached video after single viewing.